# Issue with z-order in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, z-index

Z-index problem.

```
div class="menu"...
    -----contain----
div...

div class="flash"...
    -----contain----
div...
```

In firefox the menu is over the flash contain. it's good.
but in IE7 the flash is over the menu. when menu is open(display).

Answer (score 0):

This is because Flash is embedded as a plugin into a web-site. Some browsers on some platforms (like newer Firefoxes, Safari) can handle z-indexes on plugin-tags (like object or embed), others can't (like older Firefoxes, IE). This is because for the browser the plugin is an external process, which is not a real part of the DOM of the web-site.

Short answer: you can't do anything about this, except of not using flash.

Answer (score 0):

Set `wmode="transparent"` on both the **object** and **embed** tags. Then ensure your menu has a higher z-index than the flash file.

If IE7/IE6 is is the issue, you might be dealing with the very common [IE7 z-index bug](http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/).

Comment: There is no guarantee that setting wmode to transparent will fix the z-index problem, because the core-problem is that browsers handle plugins differentely. In addition using wmode transparent will make the flash-plugin slower, even more unstable and will cause rendering bugs, especially in Gecko-based browsers.

Comment: Right, well I've been using wmode=transparent for a long time nad have never had any issues, in any browser. Suit yourselves :)